# How to get a time point from miliseconds?

Tags: c#, time

Hello everyone I have this time point struct:

```
public struct Timepoint
{
    int Hour { get; set; }
    int Minute { get; set; }
    int Second { get; set; }
    int Milisecond { get; set; }
}
```

and I'm trying to make a function to the `-` operator which currently looks like this:

```
public static Timepoint operator - (Timepoint t1, Timepoint t2)
{
    long CalcMiliseconds(Timepoint e)
    {
        return (e.Hour * 3600000) + (e.Minute * 60000) + (e.Second * 1000) + e.Milisecond;
    }

    Timepoint CalculateTimePoint(long ms)
    {
        return null;
    }

    long t1Ms = CalcMiliseconds(t1);
    long t2Ms = CalcMiliseconds(t2);

    return CalculateTimePoint(t1Ms - t2Ms);
}
```

in my local function `CalculateTimePoint`, how can I get the hour, minute, second and milliseconds back from the long number? just for context, Time point should look like `Hours:Minutes:Seconds:Milliseconds` so it needs to come back to that same format (meaning I don't want to calculate each one seperately)

Comment: Modulo, division, have you tried anything? See duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In calculateTimepoint you can use division and modulo operations to get the hours, minutes, seconds, millis by dividing ms by 3600000, taking the result, putting it into math.floor(). Now you have the hours. To get the remaining time do ms % 3600000 (modulo). Now you can continue dividing whatever the modulo operations returns and divide it by 60000 and continue like this until you have hours, minutes, seconds and millis

And then you can format the results as you please